# Sed and replacing a string

Tags: sed

I think this is something obvious, but I can't spot it.

I apply this sed

```
sed -i -e 's/\\$\\{hcvar/" + hcvar/g' -e 's/\\}/ + "/'
```

Onto this text

```
.text, r"^\$\{hcvarAuthorFirstName\}, \$\{hcvarAuthorLastName\}[\s\S]*$")
```

And it returns

```
.text, r"^" + hcvarAuthorFirstName + ", " + hcvarAuthorLastName\}[\s\S]*$")
```

All is correct, except the last part, it should be

```
.text, r"^" + hcvarAuthorFirstName + ", " + hcvarAuthorLastName + "[\s\S]*$")
```

Basically removing the `\}` and replacing with  `+ "`

It seems to work for `$\{hcvarAuthorFirstName\}` but not `$\{hcvarAuthorLastName\}`

Am I missing something?

Comment: missing the `g` flag for second regex...

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample, may i suggest:

```
sed -i -e 's/\\$\\{\(hcvar[^\\]*\)\\}/" + \1 + "/g'
```